# Store/retrieve data to/from a google spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, mpeg

Is there a way to store/retrieve values to/from the google spreadsheet cells using javascript? What I want: To store data to spreadsheet instead of database.

Comment: Yes.  Consider using Google Fusion Tables as your data source - the API is quite simple and well adapted to use in javascript.

Answer (score 2):

The Google Apps Script Developer Guide has tutorial on how to access spreadsheet data rows as Javascript objects:

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets#reading

Comment: Also see the [Full Code section of this tutorial](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/mail_merge#section-5-full-code), where the getRowsData() function will read the data into an array of objects using a header row as the index name.